# How to change absolute position of mat-menu in angular 4 material using x and y co-ordinates?

Tags: angular-material

I have following menu in angular 4

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" style="display:none;">Menu</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="select(item)">
            {{ item }}
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

I am opening the menu when user selects text on screen using 
`matMenuTrigger.openMenu();`

but I want to open menu wherever user selects text.
I have X and Y coordinates of user selection but how can I change position of menu?

I have tried giving Id to mat-menu and changing it's position using

```
element.style.position = 'absolute'
element.style.left = screenX + 'px'
element.style.top = screenY + 'px'
```

but it's not changing position of menu.

**EDIT:**
I have changed position of menu by

```
this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-pane');
menu.style.position = "absolute";
menu.style.left = evt.pageX + 5 + 'px';
menu.style.top = evt.pageY + 5 + 'px';
```

where evt is mouseup event which gives co-ordinates(X,Y) of user text selection.

But, when I scroll the page , opened menu again goes back to it's original position.
How can I keep menu to it's changed position on scroll??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have implemented opening mat-menu where ever user selectes text.

I have added hidden button which on click opens menu.
On user text selection, I have changed `style="display:none;"` of that button to `style="display:'';"` and after showing that button, I have changed position of that button to where user has selected the text by x and y co-ordinates and then opened menu programatically by `this.menuTrigger.openMenu();`

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odciv8)

**menu-example.ts**

```
export class MenuIconsExample {
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger)
    private menuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  addTextToOpns: Array<String> = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"];
  selectedOption: string = "no Option selected";
  onTextSelection(event: any):void{
    if(window.getSelection && window.getSelection().toString()){
      var menu = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
      menu.style.display = '';
      menu.style.position = 'absolute';
      menu.style.left = event.pageX + 5 + 'px';
      menu.style.top = event.pageY + 5 + 'px';

      this.menuTrigger.openMenu();  
    }

  }

  onMenuClosed():void {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
        if (menu) {
            menu.style.display = 'none';            
        }
  }

  addTextTo(selectedOpn): void {
    this.selectedOption = selectedOpn + ' selected';
  }

}
```

**menu-example.html**

```
<div (mouseup)="onTextSelection($event)">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" id="menuBtn" style="display:none;">Menu</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" (close)="onMenuClosed()">
        <button class="menuOpnBtn" mat-menu-item *ngFor="let opn of addTextToOpns" (click)="addTextTo(opn)">
            {{ opn }}
        </button>
    </mat-menu>
  <p>
    text for selection
  </p>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>


<div><span>selected option : </span> <span>{{selectedOption}}</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get this example to work in a more general case, I found it necessary to use "menu.style.position = 'fixed'   (rather than "menu.style.position = 'absolute').

This is because "event.pageX" returns the coordinates relative to the viewport.  Since "position = absolute" positions the button relative to its containing parent, the position of the invisible button will be correct only if its containing parent is not already nested in some other HTML element.

So, to summarize, I changed the code for **menu-example.ts** as follows and it now seems to work in all cases:

```
export class MenuIconsExample {
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger)
    private menuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

addTextToOpns: Array<String> = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"];
selectedOption: string = "no Option selected";
  onTextSelection(event: any):void{
    if(window.getSelection && window.getSelection().toString()){
      var menu = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
      menu.style.display = '';
      menu.style.position = 'fixed';
      menu.style.left = event.pageX + 5 + 'px';
      menu.style.top = event.pageY + 5 + 'px';

      this.menuTrigger.openMenu();  
    }

  }

  onMenuClosed():void {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
        if (menu) {
            menu.style.display = 'none';            
        }
  }

  addTextTo(selectedOpn): void {
    this.selectedOption = selectedOpn + ' selected';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you also foolishly wandering here like I wasted 3 hours of mine manually setting the position of **mat-menu** just because the triggering element of **mat-menu** disappears from the DOM on some condition and you don't want **mat-menu** to be closed at that time, then instead of using **`ngIf`** use **`hidden`** property on that triggering element, it will save your ton of time of creating some hidden element, displaying it first, getting its coordinates bla bla bla, may be that will save someones life

Answer (score 0):

The OP has edited the question to include the best answer for moving the menu position.

However, in the newer versions of angular, doing a `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection and when accessing the element, it does not have the style property. I think this is because of the update to typescript.

I found this article which helped with it ([Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element' in TS](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-property-style-not-exist-type-element#:%7E:text=If%20you%20used%20the%20document.getElementsByClassName%20method%2C%20type%20the%20collection%20as%20HTMLCollectionOf%3CHTMLElement%3E.))

The final result is this (note the setTimeout. This is done so that the mat menu can be rendered before it is moved)

```
this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
setTimeout(() => {
    const menuCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-pane') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
    const menu = menuCollection[0];
    menu.style.position = 'absolute';
    menu.style.left = e.x + 5 + 'px';
    menu.style.top = e.y + 5 + 'px';
}, 0);
```